# Insert pictures to hidden Excel file

Tags: vba, image

I am trying to insert text and pictures from a specific folder to a hidden Excel file, in specific cells, but for some reason I do not succeed in adding the pictures to the file.

What I can is open a hidden Excel file and add a bunch of data to the Excel. I can also add pictures tot the Excel from which the VBA script is running.
However combining both is something where I fail.

I use the following code to open an Excel file and put data in there:

```
Dim ExcelFileName As String
ExcelFileName = "C:\PictureTest.xlsx"

    Dim Workbook As New Excel.Application
    Dim DataWorkbook As New Excel.Workbook
    Set DataWorkbook = Workbook.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)
        Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Data to CELL"
    DataWorkbook.Save
    DataWorkbook.Close
    Set Workbook = Nothing
    Set DataWorkbook = Nothing
```

This one works perfectly, I can put data in any sheet anywhere I want.
However I also need to put pictures on certain sheets/cells.

I use the following code to add a picture to the active Excel file from which I am running the VBA script:

```
Dim PicturePath As String
PicturePath = "C:\Picture.tif"

Dim strPath As String
Dim Picture As Object
            Set Picture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicturePath)
            Picture.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
            Picture.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            Picture.ShapeRange.Width = 0.3 * Picture.Width
```

Is there anyone who can help me in getting both combined?

Comment: Calling Workbook the Excel.Application instance is not a good idea (Even if the instance was a workbook (which is not), using well known/reserved  class/object names as variable name can only confuse peoples.

Comment: Given Workbook is an Application object (sic.), Workbook.Sheets is the collection of sheets of the current ActiveWorkbook. Since you already have a reference to the workbook DataWorkbook, why not using it?

Comment: To be very honest, I have no idea how.
I do not really understand how this part works.

Comment: `DataWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Data to CELL"` instead of `Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Data to CELL"` will be clearer, easier to maintain, and less error prone...

Comment: And closing the workbook should set the reference to Nothing already, but if you want to be explicit it would be better to set the references to nothing in reverse order (the workbook object named dataworkbook before the Application object named workbook)

Comment: That indeed works. However I do not succeed to use picture.insert(picturepath) with this DataWorkbook. Is that possible?

Comment: Is there anybody who can help getting the pictures in the external excel file imported as asked above?

Comment: You can use `DataWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").`[Shapes.AddPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addpicture-method-excel)`(PicturePath , msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1)` to add the pictures in the workbook

Comment: Oh super!
Thanks a lot Vincent!!!